# Generic Issue in LocalDate

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist, comparable

I have the following code. I was expecting `Arrays.asList(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 2))` to convert into the list of `LocalDate`. But I am getting compile time error in `max(dates)`. What might be the cause of this error?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class C {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> d) {
        if (d.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        T maxValue = d.get(0);
        for (T temp : d) {
            if (maxValue.compareTo(temp) < 0) {
                maxValue = temp;
            }
        }

        return maxValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        dates.add(LocalDate.of(2015, 9, 15));
        dates.add(LocalDate.of(2010, 9, 1));

        max(dates);     //This line generates compile error.
        max(Arrays.asList(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 2)));
    }
}
```

**Compile Time Error:**
The method max(List) in the type C is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: The method max(List<T>) in the type C is not applicable for the arguments (List<LocalDate>).

Comment: `List<? extends T>` would also work in this example... (but the return type would be narrower)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` and not `Comparable<LocalDate>`

Therefore change:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> d) { ... }
```

to:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> d) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

The compile error you are getting is expected since [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) does not implement the interface `Comparable<LocalDate>`, so it does not comply to the type `T` in `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> d)`.

Instead, `LocalDate` implements `ChronoLocalDate` which itself implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`. That means that the second line (using `Arrays.asList`) actually compiles fine: the type `T` is found to be `ChronoLocalDate`.

Comment: What type of data does `Arrays.asList(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 1), LocalDate.of(2015, 2, 2))` return?

Comment: @PradipKharbuja That's the thing: you can retrieve this result in a List<LocalDate> and in a List<ChronoLocalDate> and basically in every supertype of LocalDate. But given as an argument to another generic method, the compiler will choose the "best" matching type there is (T extends Comparable<T>), which is ChronoLocalDate here.